How to Perform "Scale to Fit" for Entities in netDxf Viewports?
I am working with a DXF file using the netDxf library in C#. The file contains:
A model space where I add 2D entities such as lines, arcs, and circles (exported from Eyeshot).
Three layouts (Layout1, Layout2, Layout3), each with a viewport to display entities from the model space.
The problem I am facing is that entities added to the model space do not appear in the viewports if they are located far from the origin. However, entities placed near the origin are visible in the viewports without issue.
I suspect the issue arises because the viewport does not automatically adjust its view to fit the entities. In AutoCAD, there is a "Scale to Fit" (or "Zoom Extents") operation for viewports. I want to achieve similar functionality in netDxf, where the viewport automatically scales and centers to fit all entities in the model space.
i Have attach model data in below image
Model Entities
Layout where viewport is added
Viewport In Layout
What I Have Tried:
I verified that the entities are correctly added to the model space.
I ensured that the viewport is linked to the correct layers and entities.
Question:
Is there a built-in method in netDxf to perform a "Scale to Fit" or "Zoom Extents" operation for viewports?
If not, is there an algorithm or workaround to calculate the correct viewport center and scale to fit all entities (regardless of their distance from the origin) within the viewport?
Any guidance or example code would be greatly appreciated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
